# Install elasticsearch on windows

Tags: php, windows, elasticsearch

This might be duplicate of lot of questions...

I am trying to install elasticsearch on windows with php.
I followed below steps to install

1. Download zip and extract to c:\elasticsearch-6.3.2
2. Run .\bin\elasticsearch.bat through command line
3. Run .\bin\elasticsearch.bat -Ecluster.name=my_cluster -Enode.name=node_1 through command line

But when I try to access this url http://127.0.0.1:9200 or http://localhost:9200 through browser its showing

> "This site can’t be reached"

I tried to run through command line also like

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200
```

I am getting response as

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

I google for above error but getting answers for centos or ubuntu and not for windows.
Can anyone help, I am new to elasticsearch.

Below is log generated as elasticsearch.log

> [2018-07-31T12:34:04,301][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] []
>   initializing ... [2018-07-31T12:34:04,481][INFO
>   ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [G_YkjaN] using [1] data paths, mounts
>   [[Windows (C:)]], net usable_space [500.6mb], net total_space [100gb],
>   types [NTFS] [2018-07-31T12:34:04,481][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment
>   ] [G_YkjaN] heap size [998.4mb], compressed ordinary object pointers
>   [unknown] [2018-07-31T12:34:04,484][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ]
>   [G_YkjaN] node name derived from node ID [G_YkjaN2T66OvWgjV9A6uQ]; set
>   [node.name] to override [2018-07-31T12:34:04,484][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
>   ] [G_YkjaN] version[6.3.2], pid[3576],
>   build[default/zip/053779d/2018-07-20T05:20:23.451332Z], OS[Windows
>   8.1/6.3/x86], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM/1.8.0_25/25.25-b02] [2018-07-31T12:34:04,485][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
>   ] [G_YkjaN] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC,
>   -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\nagkatke\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:logs/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Delasticsearch, -Des.path.home=C:\elasticsearch-6.3.2, -Des.path.conf=C:\elasticsearch-6.3.2\config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=zip] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,069][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,070][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [analysis-common]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,070][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [ingest-common] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,070][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [lang-expression]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,071][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [lang-mustache] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,071][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [lang-painless]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,071][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [mapper-extras] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,073][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [parent-join]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,073][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [percolator] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,073][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [rank-eval]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,073][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [reindex] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,074][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [repository-url]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,074][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [transport-netty4] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,074][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [tribe]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,075][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-core] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,075][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module
>   [x-pack-deprecation] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,075][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,076][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-logstash] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,076][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,076][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-monitoring] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,077][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,078][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-security] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,078][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,078][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-upgrade] [2018-07-31T12:34:07,079][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:07,080][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   no plugins loaded [2018-07-31T12:34:11,043][INFO
>   ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [G_YkjaN] parsed [0] roles from file
>   [C:\elasticsearch-6.3.2\config\roles.yml]
>   [2018-07-31T12:34:11,361][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
>   org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and
>   Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the
>   other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false
>   in elasticsearch.yml  at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:102)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:93)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLearning.java:370)
>   ~[?:?]    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$7(Node.java:405)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node$$Lambda$1401/33475076.apply(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:?]    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:408)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:252)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:213)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>   [elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>   [elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2] [2018-07-31T12:34:11,372][WARN
>   ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception
>   in thread [main] org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException:
>   ElasticsearchException[X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is
>   not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features
>   (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml]
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>   ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>   ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2] Caused by:
>   org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and
>   Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the
>   other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false
>   in elasticsearch.yml  at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:102)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:93)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLearning.java:370)
>   ~[?:?]    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$7(Node.java:405)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node$$Lambda$1401/33475076.apply(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:?]    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:408)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:252)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:213)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  ... 6 more
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:54,014][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] []
>   initializing ... [2018-07-31T13:16:54,092][INFO
>   ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [G_YkjaN] using [1] data paths, mounts
>   [[Windows (C:)]], net usable_space [471.2mb], net total_space [100gb],
>   types [NTFS] [2018-07-31T13:16:54,092][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment
>   ] [G_YkjaN] heap size [998.4mb], compressed ordinary object pointers
>   [unknown] [2018-07-31T13:16:54,092][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ]
>   [G_YkjaN] node name derived from node ID [G_YkjaN2T66OvWgjV9A6uQ]; set
>   [node.name] to override [2018-07-31T13:16:54,092][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
>   ] [G_YkjaN] version[6.3.2], pid[8796],
>   build[default/zip/053779d/2018-07-20T05:20:23.451332Z], OS[Windows
>   8.1/6.3/x86], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM/1.8.0_25/25.25-b02] [2018-07-31T13:16:54,092][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
>   ] [G_YkjaN] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC,
>   -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\nagkatke\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:logs/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Delasticsearch, -Des.path.home=C:\elasticsearch-6.3.2, -Des.path.conf=C:\elasticsearch-6.3.2\config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=zip] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [analysis-common]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [ingest-common] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [lang-expression]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [lang-mustache] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [lang-painless]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [mapper-extras] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [parent-join]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [percolator] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [rank-eval]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [reindex] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [repository-url]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [transport-netty4] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [tribe]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-core] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module
>   [x-pack-deprecation] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-logstash] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,395][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-monitoring] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,411][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,411][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-security] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,411][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,411][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   loaded module [x-pack-upgrade] [2018-07-31T13:16:56,411][INFO
>   ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
>   [2018-07-31T13:16:56,411][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [G_YkjaN]
>   no plugins loaded [2018-07-31T13:17:00,453][INFO
>   ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [G_YkjaN] parsed [0] roles from file
>   [C:\elasticsearch-6.3.2\config\roles.yml]
>   [2018-07-31T13:17:00,828][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
>   org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and
>   Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the
>   other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false
>   in elasticsearch.yml  at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:102)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:93)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLearning.java:370)
>   ~[?:?]    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$7(Node.java:405)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node$$Lambda$1401/26927529.apply(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:?]    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:408)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:252)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:213)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>   [elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>   [elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86)
>   [elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2] [2018-07-31T13:17:00,843][WARN
>   ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception
>   in thread [main] org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException:
>   ElasticsearchException[X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is
>   not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features
>   (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml]
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>   ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>   ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2] Caused by:
>   org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and
>   Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the
>   other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false
>   in elasticsearch.yml  at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:102)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPlatform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:93)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLearning.java:370)
>   ~[?:?]    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$7(Node.java:405)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node$$Lambda$1401/26927529.apply(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:?]    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_25]     at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:408)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:252)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:213)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]  ... 6 more

Comment: Can you share the logs of your Elasticsearch server when it starts?

Comment: There is logs folder, which log should I share, elasticsearch.log??

Comment: I see this error message: `X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml`. It seems you've installed the standard distribution and not [the OSS one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html#install-windows).

Comment: so, what should I do to resolve above error, should I run some command or uncomment something in elasticsearch.yml

Comment: First try to add `xpack.ml.enabled: false` to `elasticserach.yml` and restart. Check if the errors are gone.

Comment: I added xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml like `#xpack.ml.enabled: false` and try to run .\bin\elasticsearch.bat this command still getting the same error

Comment: remove the pound sign `#` at the beginning of the line otherwise the line is commented

Comment: Thanks for your help and valuable time. It work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message in the logs:

> X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for
>   [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by
>   setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml

You need to add the following line in the `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and restart your ES server:

```
xpack.ml.enabled: false
```

Comment: Is there any tutorial for elasticsearch with php? Can you provide me link please?

Comment: You can start here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html